# ¿Cómo eliminar resultados repetidos de una consulta en sql Server?

Tags: sql-server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando este modelo para mi base de datos y lo que ocurre es que al querer Obtener las calificaciones finales de los alumnos, si es que tiene, aunado al su maya curricular y obtener algo como esto (Hasta acá estoy bien, esa es la maya curricular). Para este resultado estoy usando este query:

```
SELECT a.Nombre, p.NombrePrograma, c.ciclo, m.Nombre
  FROM Alumno a
  JOIN Programa p ON p.IdPrograma = a.IdPrograma
  JOIN CicloPrograma cp ON cp.IdPrograma = p.IdPrograma
  JOIN Ciclo c ON c.IdCiclo = cp.IdCiclo
  JOIN Materia m ON m.IdCicloPrograma = cp.IdCicloPrograma
  WHERE a.IdAlumno = 1
```

[image: Resultado de query maya curicular]

Pero necesito algo como esto:
[image: materias que tienen calificaciones]
Query usado

```
  SELECT a.Nombre, p.NombrePrograma, c.ciclo, m.Nombre, gm.CalificacionFinal, g.Clave AS 'Grupo', pe.Nombre As 'Periodo'
  FROM Alumno a
  JOIN Programa p ON p.IdPrograma = a.IdPrograma
  JOIN CicloPrograma cp ON cp.IdPrograma = p.IdPrograma
  JOIN Ciclo c ON c.IdCiclo = cp.IdCiclo
  JOIN Materia m ON m.IdCicloPrograma = cp.IdCicloPrograma
  JOIN MateriaOferta mo ON mo.IdMateria = m.IdMateria
  JOIN GrupoMateria gm On gm.IdMateriaOferta = mo.IdMateriaOferta
  JOIN Grupo g On g.IdGrupo = gm.IdGrupo
  JOIN Periodo pe ON pe.IdPeriodo = g.IdPeriodo
  WHERE a.IdAlumno = 1
```

Al intentar usar el Left Join para retornar todos los registros con calificaciones o sin ellas, me repite  resultados:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  SELECT a.Nombre, p.NombrePrograma, c.ciclo, m.Nombre AS 'Materia', mo.Nombre AS 'Materia Oferta', g.Clave AS 'Grupo', pe.Nombre AS 'Periodo'
  FROM Alumno a
  JOIN Programa p ON p.IdPrograma = a.IdPrograma
  JOIN CicloPrograma cp ON cp.IdPrograma = p.IdPrograma
  JOIN Ciclo c ON c.IdCiclo = cp.IdCiclo
  JOIN Materia m ON m.IdCicloPrograma = cp.IdCicloPrograma
  LEFT JOIN MateriaOferta mo ON mo.IdMateria = m.IdMateria
  LEFT JOIN GrupoMateria gm ON gm.IdMateriaOferta = mo.IdMateriaOferta
  LEFT JOIN Grupo g ON g.IdGrupo = gm.IdGrupo
  LEFT JOIN Periodo pe ON pe.IdPeriodo = g.IdPeriodo
  WHERE a.IdAlumno = 1
```

Todo perfecto con este resultado salvo que me duplica resultados en materia oferta.
**Explicación de Materia y materia oferta: Puede existir la materia Mate 1, pero para sistemas esa materia se dé de alta como Matemáticas básicas, pero para inductrial se dé de alta como: Matemáticas Iniciales. Ambas son equivalentes a Mates 1 **

Necesito obtener la maya ciruclar y las materias que hay, si es que las hay  :s Ayuda

Comment: Si tienes varias _materias oferta_  que son equivalentes a la misma materia, como has dicho en el ejemplo, ¿cómo sabes, en el modelo, cuál es la que es para un programa y cual para otro, digamos cual es para industrial y cual es para sistemas?

Comment: No es correcto asignar el IdPrograma a la tabla Alumno y a CicloPrograma, cuando toda esa información la llevas a GrupoMateria según tu modelo